# Is it possible to change the default video ProgressBar?

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm changing the UI for the controls on the video player (`PlaybackSupportFragment`) and so far I wasn't able to use a `CustomProgressBar`. This is because I need to add a moving indicator over the `Progressbar`.
The default ProgressBar is defined in `PlaybackControlsPresenter.ViewHolder` and I can't inherit this class. Actually, the code base of Leanback is pretty closed to modifications.
Is it possible to do something like this?

Btw I'm using androidx.leanback:leanback:1.1.0-alpha03